# Publish has different output when doing it from MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, orchardcms, publish

I am currently trying to set up a automated publish using MSBuild and am now realizing that it produces a different output when doing it from MSBuild instead of Visual Studio. I am not sure what I am missing here, but for some reason it is copying different project files into the route web project directory.

Is there a way to simulate a Visual Studio Publish using MSBuild? I am currently doing this with an Orchard Project, figured that would be worth mentioning.

Here is the command I am currently using to do this:

```
/p:PublishProfile="exampleprofile";DeployOnBuild=true;VisualStudioVersion=12.0;
FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v4.5";
PublishProfileRootFolder=%WORKSPACE%\src\Orchard.Web\Properties\PublishProfiles;
Password=ExamplePass;Configuration=Release
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Publish task when using MSBuild? (/p:Publish)

Comment: Do you have an example of that? There are multiple publish profiles, so I would need to specify which one

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you're trying to simulate a ClickOnce publish using a manual msbuild routine. You can achieve that by calling msbuild with the correct parameters. To simulate the ClickOnce, the target publish is available for you.

```
msbuild MyProj.csproj /t:Publish
```

Given your specifications, you have to be able to run multiple publish configurations, each one having its own output settings. To be able to run multiple profiles, I would recommend that you abandon the PublishProfile attribute (I never understood how to get it to work) and switch to the BuildEnvironment as showed here :

https://wallism.wordpress.com/2009/12/21/msbuild-and-multiple-environments/
(Focus on the "Setting up the customizations" part)

You have to adapt your call to msbuild to include your build environment

```
msbuild MyProj.csproj /t:Publish /p:BuildEnvironment=MyConfig
```

Just for a little test, for you to know if this is useful, follow the tutorial, create your target, and add a

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishUrl> Add a custom path here </PublishUrl>
    <InstallUrl> Add the same path here </InstallUrl>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to your target file.

Run then the msbuild and let me know if you solved your problem